# socket.emit() does not brodcates to all the connected devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I am using `React` and `socket.io` to transmit a message to all the connected devices. Please find the mistake. Any help is appreciated.

**App.js**

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("http://localhost:4000");

const App = () => {
  const messege = useRef(null);
  //socket functions
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("connected: " + socket.id);
  });
  socket.on("recieve", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });

  const send = () => {
    const message = messege.current.value;
    socket.emit("message", message);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Message" ref={messege} />
      <button onClick={send}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Server.js**

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const io = new Server(4000, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`connected with id: ${socket.id}`);
  socket.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
    socket.emit("recieve", msg);
  });
});
```

It only prints the message only to the emitter client(not other connected client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake for which I could not receive messages in all active clients.

The mistake was in `server.js`

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const io = new Server(4000, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`connected with id: ${socket.id}`);
  socket.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
    socket.emit("receive", msg);
    // before it was socket.emit("receive", msg);
  });
});
```

the message should be emitted from `io` instead of `socket` as we want to send all the connected user.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rooms`

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.join("receive")
  socket.join(user.id) // room for this user only (multiple connected device)

  socket.on('message', msg => {
      socket.to("receive").emit(msg)
  })
});
```